# Spark saveAsTable with location at s3 bucket's root cause NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hadoop2, spark-hive

I am working with Spark 3.0.1 and my partitioned table is stored in s3. Please find here the description of the issue.

Create Table

```
Create table root_table_test_spark_3_0_1 (
    id string,
    name string
)
USING PARQUET
PARTITIONED BY (id)
LOCATION  's3a://MY_BUCKET_NAME/'
```

Code that is causing the NullPointerException on the second run

```
Seq(MinimalObject("id_1", "name_1"), MinimalObject("id_2", "name_2"))
      .toDS()
      .write
      .partitionBy("id")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .saveAsTable("root_table_test_spark_3_0_1")
```

When the Hive metastore is empty everything is ok but the issue is happening when spark is trying to do the `getCustomPartitionLocations` in  `InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand` phase. (on the second run for example)

Indeed it calls the below method : from (`org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path`)

```
/** Adds a suffix to the final name in the path.*/
public Path suffix(String suffix) {
    return new Path(getParent(), getName()+suffix);
}
```

But the `getParent()` will return null when we are at root, resulting in a NullPointerException. The only option i'm thinking at the moment is to override this method to do something like :

```
/** Adds a suffix to the final name in the path.*/
public Path suffix(String suffix) {
    return (isRoot()) ? new Path(uri.getScheme(), uri.getAuthority(), suffix) : new Path(getParent(), getName()+suffix);
}
```

Anyone having issues when `LOCATION` of a spark hive table is at root level? Any workaround? Is there any known issues opened?

My Runtime does not allow me to override the Path class and fix the `suffix` method and i can't move my data from the bucket's root as it exists since 2 years now.

The issue happen because i'm migrating from Spark 2.1.0 to Spark 3.0.1 and the behavior checking the custom partitions appeared in Spark 2.2.0 (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16460)

This whole context help to understand the problem but basically you can reproduce it easily doing

```
val path: Path = new Path("s3a://MY_BUCKET_NAME/")
println(path.suffix("/id=id"))
```

FYI. the hadoop-common version is 2.7.4 and please find here the full stacktrace

```
NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.suffix(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.$anonfun$getCustomPartitionLocations$1(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:262)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.getCustomPartitionLocations(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:166)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a situation where the spark code calls `Path.suffix("something)` and because the root path has no parent, an NPE is triggered

Long term fix

1. File JIRA on issues.apache.org against HADOOP; provide a patch with test for fix suffix() to downgrade properly when called on root path. Best for all
2. don't use the root path as a destination of a table.
3. Do both of these

Option #2 should avoid other surprises about how tables are created/committed etc...some of the code may fail because an attempt to delete the root of the path (here s3a://some-bucket") won't delete the root, will it?

Put differently: root directories have "odd" semantics everywhere; most of the time you don't notice this on a local FS because you never try to use / as a destination of work, get surprised that rm -rf / is different from rm -rf /subdir, etc etc. Spark, Hive etc were never written to use / as a destination of work, so you get to see the failures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are confirming my thoughts and i will follow this rule as a best practice.

Comment: do file that JIRA though...it is a failing in the hadoop Path class